# Get passed parameter from url in magento

Tags: php, magento, get, magento-1.9

I am passing parameter in url and i want to get it in root file.
I am using this code but it gives me nothing.

```
require_once('../app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

echo 'Store '.Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('store').'<br>';
```

How can i get parameter from url in root file, even $_GET['store'] is not working.

Comment: post your question here it's better https://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: you will receive the parameters in the file to which you are passing. if you are passing parameters to the root file, then you will get the same in the same file. But if you are passing to some other function and you are expecting them to receive in the root file, then there is another method for this.

Answer (score 0):

//Please try with below code.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
require_once('app/Mage.php'); // Please check that this file included.
umask(0);
Mage::app();

echo 'Store '.Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('store').'<br>';
```